# converting uml to java

Tags: java, uml

So I'm BRAND NEW to Java, and one of my first exercises is to understand how to code dependencies and inheritance and such from a UML diagram. Here is the picture:

http://cs.iit.edu/~virgil/cs445/mail.spring2015/hw2-class-diagram.png

I'm still very fuzzy on syntax so please don't assume I will know what you're talking about unless it's explicitly stated. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What would the code look like for the picture at the link?

Comment: Please don't ask for others to do your schoolwork for you. Show us what you think the code should look like and we can tell you if anything's wrong.

Comment: I apologize. I'll start with what I know:

Comment: The empty arrow means inheritance, the dotted arrow means dependency, the directed arrow means directed association, and the arrow with numbers means association and multiplicity. I know C inherits from A and E inherits from C. I also know A depends on B and C depends on D. Finally D is directly associated with B, and for every 2 instances of D, there are 5 instances of F. (This is what I think, please correct me if I'm wrong). Like I said, I'm BRAND NEW to java, and I really don't know how to write the code for this. At the very least, does anyone know a good resource where I can learn this?

Comment: You're wildly off-topic for Stack Overflow, both in the original question and in your latest comment. Please look at the faq, put in some work and then if you're stuck come back with a specific question that's in scope for this site.